# Loading random forest from an RData file

Tags: r

I saved my random forest model :

```
> class(randomForestModel)
[1] "randomForest.formula" "randomForest" 
> save(randomForestModel,file = "../randomForestModel.RData")
```

later, when I am trying to load it using

```
> load("../randomForestModel.RData")
```

R loads it as character:

```
> class(randomForestModel)
[1] "character"
```

Can some one help me?

Comment: Could you include a reproducible example?

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if you at some point assign the value of `load` directly to an object. If you look in the `Value` section of `?load`: "A character vector of the names of objects created". So, yes the randomForest object is loaded to your environment, but the assignment overwrites it straight away by the 'Value' of load, the name of the object. I use an example from `?randomForest`:

```
set.seed(71)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ .,
                        data = iris, importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE)

# works
save(iris.rf, file = "iris.rf.RData")
rm(iris.rf)
load("iris.rf.RData")
class(iris.rf)
# [1] "randomForest.formula" "randomForest"

# your situation?
rm(iris.rf)
iris.rf <- load("iris.rf.RData")
class(iris.rf)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if each upvote was preceded by a face palm.  Mine was.